# python webapp2 nested PathPrefixRoute

Tags: python, webapp2

Is there a (simple) way to build the url's for webapp2 in a way that would allow a structure like below?  I couldn't see a way to pass on the PathPrefixRoute from the parent, but something like `PathPrefixRoute('(/v1)', [PathPrefixRoute('$1/app1',` would be cool.

```
urls = [
    PathPrefixRoute('/v1', [
        PathPrefixRoute('/app1', [  
            # /v1/app1/index
            Route('/index', 'v1.app1.index.Main')
        ]),
        PathPrefixRoute('/app2', [  
            # /v1/app2/index
            Route('/index', 'v1.app2.index.Main')
        ])
    ]),
    PathPrefixRoute('/v2', [
        PathPrefixRoute('/app1', [
            # /v2/app1/index
            Route('/index', 'v2.app1.index.Main')
        ])
    ])
]

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes=urls)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own custom server off uwsgi. The routing mechanism I use I have pasted below but the full application is 318 lines of goodness and can handle 100's of RPS (that's all i tested to but feel it could handle 1000's RPS) on a basic 1 core server.

Feel free to comment good, bad and ugly thoughts.

```
class Static:
    def __init__(self, s): self._s = s
    def __str__(self): return self._s

SITES = {
    '(127.0.0.1|localhost)': {
        '/': 'default.index.Home'
    },
    '(example.com)': {
        '/': 'example.index.Home',
        '/static': Static('example'),
        '/console': {
            '/': 'example.console.Home',
            '/login': 'example.console.Login'
        }
    }
}

def get_location(self):
    http_host = self.env.get('HTTP_HOST', '').split(':')[0]  # host:port
    if not http_host: raise HttpException(404, "Empty Site")
    path_info = self.env.get('PATH_INFO')
    if not path_info: raise HttpException(404, "Empty Path")
    for site in SITES:
        if re.match(site, http_host, re.I):
            paths = SITES[site]
            parts = path_info.split('/')[1:]  # first is always blank
            for part in parts:
                p = paths.copy()
                for path in p:
                    if re.match(path + '$', '/' + part, re.I):
                        if isinstance(p[path], basestring):
                            return p[path]
                        paths = p[path]
                        break
                    paths = None
                if not paths: break
            raise HttpException(404, "Unknown Path")
    raise HttpException(404, "Unknown Site")
```